A question about cyclic groups
Apologize if it is elementary, but here it goes.
I am reading Basic Algebra I second edition from Nathan Jacobson and in page 95 he is trying to prove that if there is no isomorphism with the map defined as below from $\mathbb{Z}$ to the group, then there exists a integer $p$ such that $a^p=1$.
The map as defined above is always onto, and if it is not isomorphic, then it is not injective, thus there exists some $a^n$ that is attained by another element say $a^{n-m}$, as below. I can see that under these conditions $a^{m}$ is the identity, but I am failing to understand why the effect of raising $a$ to $n$ is the same as raising $a$ to $m$. Can someone help me on how to grasp it? Thanks in advance.


I agree with Functor's answer, the author meant to write "$a^n = a^m$ for $n\ne m$," which is a direct consequence of the hypothesized lack of injectivity.  This should immediately clear up the confusion you're having with this passage, since it is now just multiplying both sides by $a^{-m}$.

Please do not rely on pictures of text.

First, the assumption in the picture is wrong (a typo of Jacobson). Change $a^{n-m} = a^n$ to $a^m = a^n$.
The question is about the intrinsics of $a^n = a^{m}$. Think about the group $\langle a \rangle$ generated by $a$. It is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ where $r$ is the least positive integer such that $a^r = 1$. An isomorphism is given by $\langle a \rangle \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p, a^i \mapsto i$. Then $a^n = a^{m}$ just means $p | n-m$.
